# Drawing multiple edges between two nodes with d3

Tags: html, graph, svg, d3.js, edges

I've been following Mike Bostock's code from [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/1153292) to learn how to draw directed graphs in d3 and was wondering how I would structure the code so that I could add multiple edges between two nodes in the graph. For example, if the dataset in the example above were defined as

```
var links = [{source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "licensing"},
             {source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "suit"},
             {source: "Samsung", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
             {source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "resolved"}];
```

and then run through the code, all I see is one line. All the paths are being drawn correctly in the html code, however they all have the same coordinates and orientation which causes the visual to look like 1 line. What kind of code restructuring would need to be done in this example to allow for the 3 edges to not be drawn on top of each other?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In fact, the original visualization is a prime example of one method to show multiple links between nodes, that is - using arcs rather than direct paths, so you can see both incoming and outgoing links.

This concept can be extended to show multiple of each of these types of links by changing the radius values of subsequent [svg path(arc)](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) elements representing the link. A basic example being

```
dr = 75/d.linknum;
```

Where `d.linknum` represents the number of the successive link.  `dr` is later used as the rx and ry amounts for the arc being drawn.

Full implementation here: http://jsfiddle.net/7HZcR/3/

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was working up a solution involving quadratic bezier curves and using Math.random() to determine the exact x and y coordinates of the reflection/control point. Your solution is much more elegant.

Comment: This is great! But it might be beneficial to post the source here in case jsfiddle ever goes down. Also, the source has comments that better explain the answer such as `any links with duplicate source and target get an incremented 'linknum'`

Comment: I am new to d3.js which i am using to show the graph & this answer helped to show the multi-edges between the nodes. I problem which i am facing is text of links are overlaping. Is there any style i have to use or d3 provides any solution for it ?

Comment: This is a good answer, however, it's not perfect. Look at this edited version : http://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/7HZcR/502/, if I click the button at the top, it fixes all the nodes, after doing this, drag the nodes around. You will notice the paths overlap :( Annoying because otherwise it works perfectly

Comment: How to keep the line straight when there isn't multiple lines?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the source for the answer above if anyone ever needs it :

```js
var links = [{source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "licensing"},
             {source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "suit"},
             {source: "Samsung", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
             {source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "resolved"}];
//sort links by source, then target
links.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a.source > b.source) {return 1;}
    else if (a.source < b.source) {return -1;}
    else {
        if (a.target > b.target) {return 1;}
        if (a.target < b.target) {return -1;}
        else {return 0;}
    }
});
//any links with duplicate source and target get an incremented 'linknum'
for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    if (i != 0 &&
        links[i].source == links[i-1].source &&
        links[i].target == links[i-1].target) {
            links[i].linknum = links[i-1].linknum + 1;
        }
    else {links[i].linknum = 1;};
};

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});

var w = 600,
    h = 600;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([w, h])
    .linkDistance(60)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

// Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
  .enter().append("svg:marker")
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

var circle = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .call(force.drag);

var text = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("g")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("svg:g");

// A copy of the text with a thick white stroke for legibility.
text.append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .attr("class", "shadow")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

text.append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

// Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
function tick() {
  path.attr("d", function(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = 75/d.linknum;  //linknum is defined above
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
  });

  circle.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });

  text.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
}
```

```css
path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

marker#licensing {
  fill: green;
}

path.link.licensing {
  stroke: green;
}

path.link.resolved {
  stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
}

circle {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

text.shadow {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

And for D3v4 see here : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4600693

Comment: I copied the path function code (leading up to `return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr`...) into a page I was working on, but all the paths came out as identical half-circles.  If this happens, the maximum radius (the `75` in `dr = 75/d.linknum;`) is too low and should be increased.

Comment: do 75*linknum @Ian

Comment: That works too, but starts with much rounder arcs and works in.

Comment: @Ian dont know if you found an answer but look at the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37417459/drawing-multiple-links-between-fixed-nodes

Comment: My initial comment contains both the problem and the solution that I found.

Comment: @hiswendy see here : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4600693 basically you draw an intermediary node that effectively pulls the link out so you can use multiple links between the same two nodes

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers using linknum, it really worked. however the lines started overlapping after linkum > 10.
Here is a function to generate equidistance quadratic curves

```
// use it like  'M' + d.source.x + ',' + d.source.y + link_arc2(d) + d.target.x + ',' + d.target.y
        function link_arc2(d) {
            // draw line for 1st link
            if (d.linknum == 1) {
                return 'L';
            }
            else {
                let sx = d.source.x;
                let sy = d.source.y;
                let tx = d.target.x;
                let ty = d.target.y;

                // distance b/w curve paths
                let cd = 30;

                // find middle of source and target
                let cx = (sx + tx) / 2;
                let cy = (sy + ty) / 2;
                
                // find angle of line b/w source and target
                var angle = Math.atan2(ty - sy, tx - sx);

                // add radian equivalent of 90 degree
                var c_angle = angle + 1.5708;

                // draw odd and even curves either side of line
                if (d.linknum & 1) {
                    return 'Q ' + (cx - ((d.linknum - 1) * cd * Math.cos(c_angle))) + ',' + (cy - ((d.linknum - 1) * cd * Math.sin(c_angle))) + ' ';
                }
                else {
                    return 'Q ' + (cx + (d.linknum * cd * Math.cos(c_angle))) + ',' + (cy + (d.linknum * cd * Math.sin(c_angle))) + ' ';
                }
            }
        }
```