# D3: Is it possible to add multiple (more than 2) edges between nodes?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am constructing a D3 force graph to visualize network traffic. Need to link two nodes with more than 2 paths. Is that possible? Help appreciated.

Comment: Looks like there is a similar question on the same topic.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368339/drawing-multiple-edges-between-two-nodes-with-d3

http://jsfiddle.net/7HZcR/3/
Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from drawing multiple edges between nodes. Then only thing is that the force directed graph layout is made for two nodes to share only one link. Thus I would recommend to do the following:

- From the force directed graph point of view have only one link.
- On the drawing point of view, draw multiple edges if both nodes have multiple edges.

Which give the following data structure for edges:

```
links = {
    source: 0, //index of source node
    target: 0 //index of target node
    representations : [{color: "red"}, {color:"blue"}]
}
```

Thus when you give links to the force directed graph, it won't complain. But when you actually draw the link you can iterate through the `representations` array to draw the different links.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But how do I iterate representation while drawing the links.
Ex:
viz.path.enter().append("path").attr("id","")... 
I use the above line to render links between nodes.
Where in this will I call representations array ?

Thanks,