# How to drag and drop nodes, if I give fixed pixel for nodes in D3 force layout

Tags: d3.js, drag-and-drop, force-layout

I put fixed positions for every nodes.

Here I can't drag and drop my nodes.

Check out the example data from:

http://jsfiddle.net/manimegala/mVmjc/2/

```
var data = {"nodes":[
                    {"name":"YHO", "full_name":"Yahoo", "type":1, "slug": "www.yahoo.com", "entity":"company", "img_hrefD":"", "img_hrefL":"","xval":"500","yval":"100"},
                    {"name":"GGL", "full_name":"Google", "type":2, "slug": "www.google.com", "entity":"company", "img_hrefD":"", "img_hrefL":"","xval":"100","yval":"200"},
                    {"name":"BNG", "full_name":"Bing", "type":2, "slug": "www.bing.com", "entity":"company", "img_hrefD":"", "img_hrefL":"","xval":"200","yval":"200"},
                    {"name":"YDX", "full_name":"Yandex", "type":2, "slug": "www.yandex.com", "entity":"company", "img_hrefD":"", "img_hrefL":"","xval":"400","yval":"200"},


                    {"name":"CEO", "prefix":"Mr.", "fst_name":"Jim", "snd_name":"Bean", "type":3, "slug": "", "entity":"employee","xval":"100","yval":"400"},
                    {"name":"ATT", "prefix":"Ms.", "fst_name":"Jenna", "snd_name":"Jameson", "type":3, "slug": "", "entity":"employee","xval":"200","yval":"400"},
                    {"name":"CTO", "prefix":"Mr.", "fst_name":"Lucky", "snd_name":"Luke", "type":3, "slug": "", "entity":"employee","xval":"300","yval":"400"},
                    {"name":"CDO", "prefix":"Ms.", "fst_name":"Pamela", "snd_name":"Anderson", "type":3, "slug": "", "entity":"employee","xval":"300","yval":"500"},
                    {"name":"CEO", "prefix":"Mr.", "fst_name":"Nacho", "snd_name":"Vidal", "type":3, "slug": "", "entity":"employee","xval":"500","yval":"500"},
                ], 
        "links":[
                    {"source":0,"target":1,"value":1,"distance":5},
                    {"source":0,"target":2,"value":1,"distance":5},
                    {"source":0,"target":3,"value":1,"distance":5},                 

                    {"source":4,"target":0,"value":1,"distance":6},
                    {"source":5,"target":1,"value":1,"distance":6},
                    {"source":6,"target":0,"value":1,"distance":6},
                    {"source":7,"target":1,"value":1,"distance":6},
                    {"source":8,"target":0,"value":1,"distance":6},
                    {"source":7,"target":8,"value":1,"distance":6},
                    ]
           }    


    var w = 560,
        h = 500,
        radius = d3.scale.log().domain([0, 312000]).range(["10", "50"]);

    var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

        //vis.append("defs").append("marker")
        //.attr("id", "arrowhead")
        //.attr("refX", 22 + 3) /*must be smarter way to calculate shift*/
        //.attr("refY", 2)
        //.attr("markerWidth", 6)
        //.attr("markerHeight", 4)
        //.attr("orient", "auto")
        //.append("path")
            //.attr("d", "M 0,0 V 4 L6,2 Z"); //this is actual shape for arrowhead

    //d3.json(data, function(json) {
        var force = self.force = d3.layout.force()
            .nodes(data.nodes)
            .links(data.links)
            .linkDistance(function(d) { return (d.distance*10); })
            //.friction(0.5)
            .charge(-250)
            .size([w, h])
            .start();



        var link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
            .data(data.links)
            .enter().append("svg:line")
            .attr("class", function (d) { return "link" + d.value +""; })
            .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
            .attr("marker-end", function(d) {
                                                if (d.value == 1) {return "url(#arrowhead)"}
                                                else    { return " " }
                                            ;});

        function fade(opacity) {

                link.style("opacity", function(d) {
                    return d.source === d || d.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
                });

            }


        function openLink() {
            return function(d) {
                var url = "";
                if(d.slug != "") {
                    url = d.slug
                } //else if(d.type == 2) {
                    //url = "clients/" + d.slug
                //} else if(d.type == 3) {
                    //url = "agencies/" + d.slug
                //}
                window.open("//"+url)
            }
        }




        var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(data.nodes)
          .enter().append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .call(force.drag);


        node.append("circle")
            .attr("class", function(d){ return "node type"+d.type})
            .attr("r",function(d){if(d.entity == "description"){ return 6 } else { return 18 }})
            //.on("mouseover", expandNode);
            //.style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.type); })



        node.append("svg:image")
            .attr("class", function(d){ return "circle img_"+d.name })
            .attr("xlink:href", function(d){ return d.img_hrefD})
            .attr("x", "-36px")
            .attr("y", "-36px")
            .attr("width", "70px")
            .attr("height", "70px")
            .on("click", openLink())
            .on("mouseover", function (d) { if(d.entity == "company")
                                                {
                    d3.select(this).attr("width", "90px")
                                    .attr("x", "-46px")
                                    .attr("y", "-36.5px")
                                   .attr("xlink:href", function(d){ return d.img_hrefL});                           
                                                }
                })
            .on("mouseout", function (d) { if(d.entity == "company")
                                            {
                    d3.select(this).attr("width", "70px")
                                    .attr("x", "-36px")
                                    .attr("y", "-36px")
                                   .attr("xlink:href", function(d){ return d.img_hrefD});
                                            }
                });    


        node.append("text")
            .attr("class", function(d){ return "nodetext title_"+d.name })
            .attr("dx", 0)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("font-size","10px")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("fill", "white")
            .text(function(d) { if (d.entity != "description"){return d.name} });



        node.on("mouseover", function (d) {
            link.style('stroke-width', function(l) {
                if (d === l.source || d === l.target)
                return 4;
              else
                return 2;
            });
            if (d.entity == "company"){   
                d3.select(this).select('text')
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)
                    .text(function(d){
                            return d.full_name;
                        })
                    .style("font-size","15px")

            }
            else if(d.entity == "employee"){
                var asdf = d3.select(this);
                asdf.select('text').remove();

                asdf.append("text")
                            .text(function(d){return d.prefix + ' ' + d.fst_name })
                            .attr("class","nodetext")
                            .attr("dx", 0)
                            .attr("dy", ".35em")
                            .style("font-size","5px")
                            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                            .style("fill", "white")
                            .transition()
                            .duration(300)
                            .style("font-size","12px");

                asdf.append("text").text(function(d){return d.snd_name })
                            .attr("class","nodetext")
                            .attr("transform","translate(0, 12)")
                            .attr("dx", 0)
                            .attr("dy", ".35em")
                            .style("font-size","5px")
                            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                            .style("fill", "white")
                            .transition()
                            .duration(300)
                            .style("font-size","12px");                                         
            }
            else {
                d3.select(this).select('text')
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)
                    .style("font-size","15px")
            }

            if (d.entity == "company") {
                d3.select(this).select('image')
                    .attr("width", "90px")
                    .attr("x", "-46px")
                    .attr("y", "-36.5px")
                    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
                        return d.img_hrefL
                        });               
            }

            if (d.entity == "company") {

                d3.select(this).select('circle')
                                .transition()
                                .duration(300)
                                .attr("r",28)

            }
            else if (d.entity == "employee"){
                d3.select(this).select('circle')
                                .transition()
                                .duration(300)
                                .attr("r",32)
            }
        })


         node.on("mouseout", function (d) {
            link.style('stroke-width', 2);
            if (d.entity == "company") {
                d3.select(this).select('text')
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)
                    .text(function(d){return d.name;})
                    .style("font-size","10px")
                }
            else if(d.entity == "employee"){
                ///////////////////////////
                // CHANGE
                ///////////////////////////

                d3.select(this).selectAll('text').remove();

                //d3.select(this).select('text')
                d3.select(this).append('text')
                    .text(function(d){return d.name;})
                    .style("font-size","14px")  
                    .attr("dx", 0)
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .style("fill", "white")
                    .attr("class","nodetext")
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)
                    .style("font-size","10px")

            }
            else {
                d3.select(this).select('text')
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)
                    .style("font-size","10px")
            }


             if (d.entity == "company") {
                d3.select(this).select('image')
                    .attr("width", "70px")
                    .attr("x", "-36px")
                    .attr("y", "-36px")
                    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
                    return d.img_hrefD
                });
            }

            if (d.entity == "company" || d.entity == "employee") {

                d3.select(this).select('circle')
                                .transition()
                                .duration(300)
                                .attr("r",18)
            }

        });

        force.on("tick", function() {
          link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.xval; })
              .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.yval; })
              .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.xval; })
              .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.yval; });

          node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.xval + "," + d.yval + ")"; });
        });
    //});
```

Comment: refer this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558

Answer (score 0):

You need to set and use the `.x` and `.y` attributes for the coordinates, as this is what the force layout uses. Then you just need to set `.fixed` for all the nodes. The following block of code, run at the very beginning, does this.

```
data.nodes.forEach(function(n) {
            n.fixed = true;
            n.x = +n.xval;
            n.y = +n.yval;
        });
```

The only other change is to use `.x` and `.y` in the `tick` handler function:

```
force.on("tick", function() {
          link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
              .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
              .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
              .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

          node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
        });
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mVmjc/4/).

Comment: thank you. how to get all nodes x and y positions when i click button

Comment: You would need to attach a click handler and iterate over `nodes`.

Comment: yes thank you. when i drag my nodes. it will go off from svg boundary(width,height). how to limit to drag and drop up to svg boundary.

Comment: You can do this in the `tick` handler by limiting the coordinates you set.

Comment: E.g. `node.forEach(function(n) { n.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(n.x, width)); });` and similarly for `n.y`.

Comment: `node.forEach(function(n) { 
    n.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(n.x, w));
    n.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(n.y, h));
   }); `   I added this code but it's not working.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `data.nodes.forEach` -- http://jsfiddle.net/mVmjc/5/

Comment: How to draw multiple links between two node.Link line should not be arc. Please help me. Is that possible?

Comment: You can open a separate question about this, but I suggest that you search the examples before. In particular [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368339/drawing-multiple-edges-between-two-nodes-with-d3) should help.

Comment: I have added new question [My Qustion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274870/multiple-straight-line-between-two-node-in-d3-js)