# Graph different multiedges javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I am searching for a way to build a multi-edge graph with **Javascript**.

The edges have to be different in color and thickness. Data for building it comes from a json file.

I already looked into **d3.js**, But the forced layout isn't what I am looking for, so please don't link my question to solutions with forced layout!

The treelayout offers no multiple edges or does it?

Any other way to get 5 edges between every node wich show a different grade of flow?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing multiple edges between two nodes with d3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368339/drawing-multiple-edges-between-two-nodes-with-d3)