# D3 Force Layout Graph - Arc Path

Tags: d3.js

I have the following code that works, but I have two problems I need help with.

1. The path line draws pass the arrow underneath the icon. How can I
   force the path line from stopping at the arrow point?
2. Some nodes can have two links and they overlap. How can I swap the
   ARC direction on the second link to prevent that from happening?

   ```
   var json_data = data;

   var hash_lookup = [];
   json_data.nodes.forEach(function (d, i) {
     hash_lookup[d.id] = d;
   });
   json_data.links.forEach(function (d, i) {
     d.source = hash_lookup[d.source];
     d.target = hash_lookup[d.target];
   });

   var width = ($("#dependency_map").width()-10);
   var height = ($("#dependency_map").height()-10);

   d3.select("#dependency_map").selectAll("*").remove();


   var force = d3.layout.force()
       .gravity(.05)
       .distance(100)
       .linkStrength(.4)
       .charge(-200)
       .size([width, height]);



   var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
       .scaleExtent([1, 10])
       .on("zoom", zoomed);

   var svg = d3.select("#dependency_map")
       .append("svg:svg")
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height)
       .attr("pointer-events", "all")
       .append('svg:g')
       .call(zoom).on("dblclick.zoom", null)

   var rect = svg.append("rect")
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height)
       .style("fill", "none")
       .style("pointer-events", "all");

   function dblclick(d) {
     d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
   }

   function dragstarted(d) {
     if(d3.event.sourceEvent.button == 0) {
       d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
       force.start();
     }
   }

   function dragged(d) {
     if(d3.event.sourceEvent.button == 0) {
       d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
     }
   }

   function dragended(d) {
     if(d3.event.sourceEvent.button == 0) {
       d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
       d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
     }
   }

   var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
       .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
       .on("drag", dragged)
       .on("dragend", dragended);


   var nodes = json_data.nodes,
       links = json_data.links;

   var container = svg.append("g");


   // build the arrow.
   container.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
       .data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
       .enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
       .attr("id", String)
       .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
       .attr("refX", 15)
       .attr("refY", -1.5)
       .attr("markerWidth", 6)
       .attr("markerHeight", 6)
       .attr("orient", "auto")
       .append("svg:path")
       .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

   // make an arch between nodes and a text label in the middle
   var path = container.selectAll("path.link").data(links);
   path.enter().append("path")
       .attr("class", "link")
       .attr("id",function(d,i) { return "linkId_" + i; })
       .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

   var linktext = container.append("svg:g").selectAll("g.linklabelholder").data(links);

   linktext.enter().append("g").attr("class", "linklabelholder")
       .append("text")
       .attr("class", "linklabel")
       .style("font-size", "0.5em")
       .attr("dy", "-2")
       .style("fill","#000")
       .append("textPath")
       .attr("startOffset","50%")
       .style("text-anchor","middle")
       .attr("xlink:href",function(d,i) { return "#linkId_" + i;})
       .text(function(d) {
         return d.text;
       });


   var node = container.selectAll("g.node")
       .data(nodes)
       .enter()
       .append("svg:g")
       .attr("class", "node")
       .on("dblclick", dblclick)
       .call(drag)
       .on("contextmenu", function(data, index) {
         console.log("Context Menu Click");
         if (data.knownworkload == true)
         {
           d3.select('#cntxtMenu')
               .style('position', 'absolute')
               .style('left', data.px + 50 + "px")
               .style('top', data.py + "px")
               .style('display', 'block')
               .on('mouseleave', function() {
                 d3.select('#cntxtMenu').style('display', 'none');
                 context = null;
               });
           d3.selectAll('.workload_menu').on('click' , function(d) {
             var action = d3.select(this).attr("action");
             var workload_id = data.guid;
             if (action == "information")
             {
               $.ajax({
                 async:true,
                 url: "<%= url(format: :js) %>",
                 data: {
                   workload_id: workload_id
                 }
               });
               $('#cntxtMenu').hide();
             }
             else
             {
               var servicestack_id = d3.select(this).attr("guid");
               $.ajax({
                 async:false,
                 url: "<%= url %>",
                 data: {
                   workload_id: workload_id,
                   servicestack_id: servicestack_id,
                   success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                   },
                 }
               });
               draw_map();
               $('#cntxtMenu').hide();
             }

           });
         }
         d3.event.preventDefault();
       });

   function zoomed() {
     container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
   }


   nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
     d.x = width/2 + i;
     d.y = height/2 + (1500 * d.depth);
   });

   force.nodes(nodes)
       .links(links)
       .start();



   node.append('svg:text')
       .attr('font-family', function (d) {
         return d.icon.fontfamily;
       })
       .attr('font-size', '0.8em')
       .attr('fill', function (d) {
         return d.icon.color;})
       .text(function (d) {return d.icon.icon;})
       .attr("x", "-5px")
       .attr("y", "5px");

   node.append("svg:text")
       .attr("y", "15px")
       .attr('font-size', '0.6em')
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .each(function (d) {
         var arr = d.name.split(" ");
         if (arr != undefined) {
           for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
             d3.select(this).append("tspan")
                 .text(arr[i])
                 .attr("cy", (i == 0) ? 0 : 10)
                 .attr("text-anchor", "left")
                 .attr("class", "nodetext");
           }
         }
       });

   for (var i=0; i<path.length; i++) {
     if (i != 0 &&
         path[i].source == path[i-1].source &&
         path[i].target == path[i-1].target) {
       path[i].linknum = path[i-1].linknum + 1;
     }
     else {path[i].linknum = 1;};
   };

   node.append("svg:title")
       .text(function (d) {
         return d.tooltip;
       });

   force.on("tick", function(e) {
     path.attr("d", function(d) {
       console.log(d);
       var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
           dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
           dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
       return "M" +
           d.source.x + "," +
           d.source.y + "A" +
           dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " +
           d.target.x + "," +
           d.target.y;
     });
     node.attr("transform", function (d) {
       return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
     });

   });
   ```

   },
   });

Comment: Set up a jsfiddle so we can help with the arc situation. As far as the multiple links look at this great example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368339/drawing-multiple-edges-between-two-nodes-with-d3