# Use d3 link nodes with mutiple lines for diffrent relations?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I can through target and source to link nodes with one line easily.
[image]

but how can link nodes with multiple lines? like:

[image]

or:

[image]

Comment: Don't use lines, use paths: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11368339/5768908

Comment: And how to add text on the middle of the line?

Comment: Use a text path: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath